# Effect of removing a Hamiltonian cycle on the Laplacian spectrum

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, laplacian, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, eigenvalues

Notation: $\lambda_{\max}(G)$ is the largest eigenvalue of the Laplacian matrix of the graph $G$ (aka the Laplacian index of $G$).

Now suppose $G$ is a Hamiltonian graph with Hamiltonian cycle $C$.

> Is there a non-trivial lower bound on
>   $\lambda_{\max}(G)-\lambda_{\max}(G-C)$?